# VPN doesn't work when using wi-fi

Tags: network-manager, vpn

I recently changed my router to a Huawei EG8145V5 and I need to connect to my company's VPN to work.
When I'm using ethernet, connection works as expected, but when I switch to wifi it doens't work.

My VPN configs are:

L2TP IPsec Options disabled

IPv4 and IPv6 Automatic

[image: VPN Configs]

This is the syslog when I connect to the VPN using wifi

```
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: <info>  [1602548888.0293] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5" name="OFFICE" pid=5649 uid=1000 result="success"
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr gnome-shell[1541]: JS ERROR: TypeError: item is undefined#012setActiveConnections/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1520:17#012setActiveConnections@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1517:9#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012_syncVpnConnections@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1855:9#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: <info>  [1602548888.0382] vpn-connection[0x55b64b8de770,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 20787
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: <info>  [1602548888.0447] vpn-connection[0x55b64b8de770,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: <info>  [1602548888.0509] vpn-connection[0x55b64b8de770,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr nm-l2tp-service[20787]: Check port 1701
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr nm-l2tp-service[20787]: Can't bind to port 1701
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr nm-l2tp-service[20787]: xl2tpd started with pid 20790
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: Not looking for kernel SAref support.
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: Using l2tp kernel support.
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: xl2tpd version xl2tpd-1.3.10 started on pvqr PID:20790
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: Written by Mark Spencer, Copyright (C) 1998, Adtran, Inc.
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: Forked by Scott Balmos and David Stipp, (C) 2001
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: Inherited by Jeff McAdams, (C) 2002
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: Forked again by Xelerance (www.xelerance.com) (C) 2006-2016
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: Listening on IP address 0.0.0.0, port 60466
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: Connecting to host WORK-IP-HERE, port 1701
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: <info>  [1602548888.0526] vpn-connection[0x55b64b8de770,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: starting (3)
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: Connection established to WORK-IP-HERE, 1701.  Local: 62261, Remote: 6533 (ref=0/0).
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: Calling on tunnel 62261
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: Call established with WORK-IP-HERE, Local: 15566, Remote: 1, Serial: 1 (ref=0/0)
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: start_pppd: I'm running:
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: "/usr/sbin/pppd"
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: "plugin"
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: "pppol2tp.so"
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: "pppol2tp"
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: "7"
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: "passive"
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: "nodetach"
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: ":"
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: "file"
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: "/var/run/nm-l2tp-ppp-options-47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5"
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr pppd[20791]: Plugin pppol2tp.so loaded.
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr pppd[20791]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.7/nm-l2tp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr pppd[20791]: pppd 2.4.7 started by root, uid 0
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr pppd[20791]: Using interface ppp0
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr pppd[20791]: Connect: ppp0 <-->
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr pppd[20791]: Overriding mtu 1500 to 1400
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr pppd[20791]: Overriding mru 1500 to mtu value 1400
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr systemd-udevd[20794]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: <info>  [1602548888.1730] manager: (ppp0): new Ppp device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/40)
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: <info>  [1602548888.1970] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: <info>  [1602548888.1971] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr pppd[20791]: Overriding mtu 1450 to 1400
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr pppd[20791]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr pppd[20791]: local  IP address 10.10.1.48
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr pppd[20791]: remote IP address 10.10.1.1
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr pppd[20791]: primary   DNS address 1.1.1.1
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr pppd[20791]: secondary DNS address 8.8.8.8
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: <info>  [1602548888.4113] device (ppp0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: <info>  [1602548888.4125] device (ppp0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: <info>  [1602548888.4165] vpn-connection[0x55b64b8de770,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",0]: VPN connection: (IP4 Config Get) reply received from old-style plugin
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: <info>  [1602548888.4170] vpn-connection[0x55b64b8de770,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",40:(ppp0)]: Data: VPN Gateway: WORK-IP-HERE
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: <info>  [1602548888.4171] vpn-connection[0x55b64b8de770,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",40:(ppp0)]: Data: Tunnel Device: "ppp0"
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: <info>  [1602548888.4171] vpn-connection[0x55b64b8de770,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",40:(ppp0)]: Data: IPv4 configuration:
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: <info>  [1602548888.4171] vpn-connection[0x55b64b8de770,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",40:(ppp0)]: Data:   Internal Address: 10.10.1.48
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: <info>  [1602548888.4171] vpn-connection[0x55b64b8de770,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",40:(ppp0)]: Data:   Internal Prefix: 32
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: <info>  [1602548888.4171] vpn-connection[0x55b64b8de770,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",40:(ppp0)]: Data:   Internal Point-to-Point Address: 10.10.1.1
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: <info>  [1602548888.4171] vpn-connection[0x55b64b8de770,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",40:(ppp0)]: Data:   Static Route: 0.0.0.0/0   Next Hop: 0.0.0.0
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: <info>  [1602548888.4171] vpn-connection[0x55b64b8de770,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",40:(ppp0)]: Data:   Static Route: 10.10.1.1/32   Next Hop: 0.0.0.0
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: <info>  [1602548888.4171] vpn-connection[0x55b64b8de770,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",40:(ppp0)]: Data:   Internal DNS: 1.1.1.1
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: <info>  [1602548888.4171] vpn-connection[0x55b64b8de770,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",40:(ppp0)]: Data:   Internal DNS: 8.8.8.8
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: <info>  [1602548888.4172] vpn-connection[0x55b64b8de770,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",40:(ppp0)]: Data:   DNS Domain: '(none)'
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: <info>  [1602548888.4172] vpn-connection[0x55b64b8de770,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",40:(ppp0)]: Data: No IPv6 configuration
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: <info>  [1602548888.4172] vpn-connection[0x55b64b8de770,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",40:(ppp0)]: VPN plugin: state changed: started (4)
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: <info>  [1602548888.4187] vpn-connection[0x55b64b8de770,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",40:(ppp0)]: VPN connection: (IP Config Get) complete
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr dbus-daemon[809]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.13' (uid=0 pid=876 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr dbus-daemon[809]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr nm-dispatcher: req:1 'vpn-up' [ppp0]: new request (1 scripts)
Oct 12 21:28:08 pvqr nm-dispatcher: req:1 'vpn-up' [ppp0]: start running ordered scripts...
Oct 12 21:28:12 pvqr systemd-resolved[603]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 8.8.8.8.
Oct 12 21:28:12 pvqr systemd-resolved[603]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 1.1.1.1.
Oct 12 21:28:17 pvqr systemd-resolved[603]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 8.8.8.8.
Oct 12 21:28:20 pvqr whoopsie[2034]: [21:28:20] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Oct 12 21:28:20 pvqr whoopsie[2034]: [21:28:20] offline
Oct 12 21:28:20 pvqr org.gnome.Shell.desktop[5649]: [6418:6442:1012/212820.429208:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(428)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -105
Oct 12 21:28:27 pvqr systemd-resolved[603]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 1.1.1.1.
Oct 12 21:28:52 pvqr org.gnome.Shell.desktop[5649]: [6418:6442:1012/212852.817218:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(428)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -105
Oct 12 21:28:54 pvqr systemd[1]: Starting Message of the Day...
Oct 12 21:28:54 pvqr systemd[1]: Started Message of the Day.
Oct 12 21:28:58 pvqr systemd-resolved[603]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 1.1.1.1.
Oct 12 21:29:03 pvqr systemd-resolved[603]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 8.8.8.8.
Oct 12 21:29:09 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: check_control: Received out of order control packet on tunnel 6533 (got 2, expected 3)
Oct 12 21:29:09 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: handle_packet: bad control packet!
Oct 12 21:29:10 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: check_control: Received out of order control packet on tunnel 6533 (got 2, expected 3)
Oct 12 21:29:10 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: handle_packet: bad control packet!
Oct 12 21:29:12 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: check_control: Received out of order control packet on tunnel 6533 (got 2, expected 3)
Oct 12 21:29:12 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: handle_packet: bad control packet!
Oct 12 21:29:16 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: check_control: Received out of order control packet on tunnel 6533 (got 2, expected 3)
Oct 12 21:29:16 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: handle_packet: bad control packet!
Oct 12 21:29:19 pvqr systemd-resolved[603]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 8.8.8.8.
Oct 12 21:29:19 pvqr systemd-resolved[603]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 1.1.1.1.
Oct 12 21:29:24 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: check_control: Received out of order control packet on tunnel 6533 (got 2, expected 3)
Oct 12 21:29:24 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: handle_packet: bad control packet!
Oct 12 21:29:39 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: Maximum retries exceeded for tunnel 62261.  Closing.
Oct 12 21:29:39 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: Terminating pppd: sending TERM signal to pid 20791
Oct 12 21:29:39 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: Connection 6533 closed to WORK-IP-HERE, port 1701 (Timeout)
Oct 12 21:29:39 pvqr pppd[20791]: Terminating on signal 15
Oct 12 21:29:39 pvqr pppd[20791]: Connect time 1.6 minutes.
Oct 12 21:29:39 pvqr pppd[20791]: Sent 8595 bytes, received 0 bytes.
Oct 12 21:29:39 pvqr org.gnome.Shell.desktop[5649]: [6418:6442:1012/212939.190938:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(428)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -105
Oct 12 21:29:39 pvqr whoopsie[2034]: [21:29:39] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Oct 12 21:29:39 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: <info>  [1602548979.1944] device (ppp0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 12 21:29:39 pvqr pppd[20791]: Overriding mtu 1500 to 1400
Oct 12 21:29:39 pvqr pppd[20791]: Overriding mru 1500 to mtu value 1400
Oct 12 21:29:40 pvqr whoopsie[2034]: [21:29:40] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Oct 12 21:29:41 pvqr org.gnome.Shell.desktop[5649]: [6418:6442:1012/212941.199394:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(428)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -105
Oct 12 21:29:45 pvqr pppd[20791]: Connection terminated.
Oct 12 21:29:45 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: xl2tpd[20790]: death_handler: Fatal signal 15 received
Oct 12 21:29:45 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: <info>  [1602548985.2050] vpn-connection[0x55b64b8de770,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",40:(ppp0)]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
Oct 12 21:29:45 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: <info>  [1602548985.2072] vpn-connection[0x55b64b8de770,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",40:(ppp0)]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
Oct 12 21:29:45 pvqr dbus-daemon[809]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.13' (uid=0 pid=876 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Oct 12 21:29:45 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: <info>  [1602548985.2297] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Oct 12 21:29:45 pvqr NetworkManager[876]: <info>  [1602548985.2297] vpn-connection[0x55b64b8de770,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",0]: VPN service disappeared
Oct 12 21:29:45 pvqr systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Oct 12 21:29:45 pvqr gnome-shell[1541]: Removing a network device that was not added
Oct 12 21:29:45 pvqr pppd[20791]: Modem hangup
Oct 12 21:29:45 pvqr pppd[20791]: Exit.
Oct 12 21:29:45 pvqr dbus-daemon[809]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Oct 12 21:29:45 pvqr systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Oct 12 21:29:45 pvqr nm-dispatcher: req:1 'vpn-down' [ppp0]: new request (1 scripts)
Oct 12 21:29:45 pvqr nm-dispatcher: req:1 'vpn-down' [ppp0]: start running ordered scripts...
Oct 12 21:29:45 pvqr whoopsie[2034]: [21:29:45] online
Oct 12 21:29:45 pvqr gnome-shell[5649]: Removing a network device that was not added
Oct 12 21:29:45 pvqr systemd-resolved[603]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
```

I'm suspicious it has something to do with IPv6, but can't confirm. I couldn't find anything about VPN, GRE Protocol or Passthrough on my router configuration menu. How can I make it work using wifi or get a better understanding on what is failing?

Running Ubuntu 18.04.5

Logs from when I connect to the vpn while using ethernet:

```
Oct 13 08:05:20 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: <info>  [1602587120.8696] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5" name="OFFICE" pid=5656 uid=1000 result="success"
Oct 13 08:05:20 pvqr gnome-shell[1540]: JS ERROR: TypeError: item is undefined#012setActiveConnections/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1520:17#012setActiveConnections@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1517:9#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012_syncVpnConnections@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1855:9#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
Oct 13 08:05:20 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: <info>  [1602587120.8844] vpn-connection[0x564de74442c0,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 7950
Oct 13 08:05:20 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: <info>  [1602587120.9011] vpn-connection[0x564de74442c0,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
Oct 13 08:05:20 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: <info>  [1602587120.9078] vpn-connection[0x564de74442c0,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
Oct 13 08:05:20 pvqr nm-l2tp-service[7950]: Check port 1701
Oct 13 08:05:20 pvqr nm-l2tp-service[7950]: Can't bind to port 1701
Oct 13 08:05:20 pvqr nm-l2tp-service[7950]: xl2tpd started with pid 7953
Oct 13 08:05:20 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: xl2tpd[7953]: Not looking for kernel SAref support.
Oct 13 08:05:20 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: xl2tpd[7953]: Using l2tp kernel support.
Oct 13 08:05:20 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: xl2tpd[7953]: xl2tpd version xl2tpd-1.3.10 started on pvqr PID:7953
Oct 13 08:05:20 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: xl2tpd[7953]: Written by Mark Spencer, Copyright (C) 1998, Adtran, Inc.
Oct 13 08:05:20 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: xl2tpd[7953]: Forked by Scott Balmos and David Stipp, (C) 2001
Oct 13 08:05:20 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: xl2tpd[7953]: Inherited by Jeff McAdams, (C) 2002
Oct 13 08:05:20 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: xl2tpd[7953]: Forked again by Xelerance (www.xelerance.com) (C) 2006-2016
Oct 13 08:05:20 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: xl2tpd[7953]: Listening on IP address 0.0.0.0, port 40438
Oct 13 08:05:20 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: <info>  [1602587120.9097] vpn-connection[0x564de74442c0,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: starting (3)
Oct 13 08:05:20 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: xl2tpd[7953]: Connecting to host WORK-IP-HERE, port 1701
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: xl2tpd[7953]: Connection established to WORK-IP-HERE, 1701.  Local: 1038, Remote: 6538 (ref=0/0).
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: xl2tpd[7953]: Calling on tunnel 1038
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: xl2tpd[7953]: Call established with WORK-IP-HERE, Local: 44017, Remote: 1, Serial: 1 (ref=0/0)
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: xl2tpd[7953]: start_pppd: I'm running:
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: xl2tpd[7953]: "/usr/sbin/pppd"
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: xl2tpd[7953]: "plugin"
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: xl2tpd[7953]: "pppol2tp.so"
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: xl2tpd[7953]: "pppol2tp"
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: xl2tpd[7953]: "7"
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: xl2tpd[7953]: "passive"
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: xl2tpd[7953]: "nodetach"
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: xl2tpd[7953]: ":"
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: xl2tpd[7953]: "file"
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: xl2tpd[7953]: "/var/run/nm-l2tp-ppp-options-47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5"
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr pppd[7954]: Plugin pppol2tp.so loaded.
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr pppd[7954]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.7/nm-l2tp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr pppd[7954]: pppd 2.4.7 started by root, uid 0
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr pppd[7954]: Using interface ppp0
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr pppd[7954]: Connect: ppp0 <-->
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr pppd[7954]: Overriding mtu 1500 to 1400
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr pppd[7954]: Overriding mru 1500 to mtu value 1400
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr systemd-udevd[7957]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: <info>  [1602587121.1399] manager: (ppp0): new Ppp device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/30)
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: <info>  [1602587121.1729] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: <info>  [1602587121.1730] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr pppd[7954]: Overriding mtu 1450 to 1400
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr pppd[7954]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr charon: 09[KNL] 10.10.1.2 appeared on ppp0
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr charon: 14[KNL] 10.10.1.2 disappeared from ppp0
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr charon: 08[KNL] 10.10.1.2 appeared on ppp0
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr charon: 16[KNL] interface ppp0 activated
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr pppd[7954]: local  IP address 10.10.1.2
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr pppd[7954]: remote IP address 10.10.1.1
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr pppd[7954]: primary   DNS address 1.1.1.1
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr pppd[7954]: secondary DNS address 8.8.8.8
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: <info>  [1602587121.3692] device (ppp0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: <info>  [1602587121.3728] device (ppp0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: <info>  [1602587121.3781] vpn-connection[0x564de74442c0,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",0]: VPN connection: (IP4 Config Get) reply received from old-style plugin
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: <info>  [1602587121.3792] vpn-connection[0x564de74442c0,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",30:(ppp0)]: Data: VPN Gateway: WORK-IP-HERE
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: <info>  [1602587121.3792] vpn-connection[0x564de74442c0,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",30:(ppp0)]: Data: Tunnel Device: "ppp0"
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: <info>  [1602587121.3793] vpn-connection[0x564de74442c0,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",30:(ppp0)]: Data: IPv4 configuration:
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: <info>  [1602587121.3793] vpn-connection[0x564de74442c0,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",30:(ppp0)]: Data:   Internal Address: 10.10.1.2
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: <info>  [1602587121.3793] vpn-connection[0x564de74442c0,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",30:(ppp0)]: Data:   Internal Prefix: 32
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: <info>  [1602587121.3793] vpn-connection[0x564de74442c0,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",30:(ppp0)]: Data:   Internal Point-to-Point Address: 10.10.1.1
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: <info>  [1602587121.3793] vpn-connection[0x564de74442c0,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",30:(ppp0)]: Data:   Static Route: 0.0.0.0/0   Next Hop: 0.0.0.0
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: <info>  [1602587121.3794] vpn-connection[0x564de74442c0,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",30:(ppp0)]: Data:   Static Route: 10.10.1.1/32   Next Hop: 0.0.0.0
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: <info>  [1602587121.3794] vpn-connection[0x564de74442c0,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",30:(ppp0)]: Data:   Internal DNS: 1.1.1.1
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: <info>  [1602587121.3794] vpn-connection[0x564de74442c0,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",30:(ppp0)]: Data:   Internal DNS: 8.8.8.8
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: <info>  [1602587121.3794] vpn-connection[0x564de74442c0,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",30:(ppp0)]: Data:   DNS Domain: '(none)'
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: <info>  [1602587121.3794] vpn-connection[0x564de74442c0,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",30:(ppp0)]: Data: No IPv6 configuration
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: <info>  [1602587121.3795] vpn-connection[0x564de74442c0,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",30:(ppp0)]: VPN plugin: state changed: started (4)
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr NetworkManager[839]: <info>  [1602587121.3821] vpn-connection[0x564de74442c0,47728854-1e76-453e-8226-87b565571bd5,"OFFICE",30:(ppp0)]: VPN connection: (IP Config Get) complete
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr dbus-daemon[814]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.9' (uid=0 pid=839 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr dbus-daemon[814]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr nm-dispatcher: req:1 'vpn-up' [ppp0]: new request (1 scripts)
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr nm-dispatcher: req:1 'vpn-up' [ppp0]: start running ordered scripts...
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr org.gnome.Shell.desktop[5656]: [6021:7029:1013/080521.495423:ERROR:dns_config_service_posix.cc(442)] DNS config watch failed.
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr org.gnome.Shell.desktop[5656]: [6068:7710:1013/080521.495553:ERROR:dns_config_service_posix.cc(442)] DNS config watch failed.
Oct 13 08:05:23 pvqr systemd-resolved[630]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 1.1.1.1.
Oct 13 08:05:23 pvqr systemd-resolved[630]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 8.8.8.8.
Oct 13 08:05:25 pvqr systemd-resolved[630]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 1.1.1.1.
Oct 13 08:05:27 pvqr systemd-resolved[630]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 8.8.8.8.
Oct 13 08:05:31 pvqr whoopsie[2028]: [08:05:31] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Oct 13 08:05:33 pvqr org.gnome.Shell.desktop[5656]: [6021:6049:1013/080533.381921:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(428)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -105
Oct 13 08:05:40 pvqr whoopsie[2028]: [08:05:40] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Oct 13 08:05:45 pvqr dbus-daemon[814]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.206' (uid=1000 pid=8231 comm="gnome-control-center network " label="unconfined")
Oct 13 08:05:45 pvqr systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Oct 13 08:05:45 pvqr dbus-daemon[814]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Oct 13 08:05:45 pvqr systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Oct 13 08:05:45 pvqr systemd-resolved[630]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 1.1.1.1.
Oct 13 08:05:45 pvqr org.gnome.Shell.desktop[5656]: Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
Oct 13 08:05:55 pvqr systemd-resolved[630]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 1.1.1.1.
```

Router IP configs

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you connect to the ethernet and produce the same log and compare? is the DNS configuration for the wifi the same as the one for ethernet?

Comment: I updated my question with the ethernet log. It seams that the DNS configs are the same for wifi and ethernet.

Comment: Are you using the same device when trying to connect both ways?

Comment: Yes, it's the same notebook. I tried with two different notebooks (Ubuntu 20 and 18), same problem. Which makes me think there is something wrong with the router wifi configuration.

Comment: I'd look at dropped packets with `ip -s link` or ifconfig or whatever you usually use... I'd play with the mtu sizes to see if it makes a difference... I'd also want to know if i am usually dropping packets, not just with the vpn on...

Comment: @PedroRocha If your wifi turns out to be stable and maintains a solid connection, I would try to connect the vpn on some other wifi first.... go to Mcdonalds or the library... or if you have another wireless access point available that you could connect up to your router via ethernet (i know know one likes to take their router down)... you could also make sure it isnt the software, try a different connection software.... even try with your phone's software through your wifi if it has the feature... isolate the problem, make sure it's not the wifi's software/config vs the wifi

Comment: @WU-TANG My phone was unable to connect too. I moved to a new house two days ago, before that I used to connect to the VPN using this pc with no problems. It's even the same ISP, the real only difference is they gave me a new and more powerful router, with ipv6 support and a 5Ghz wireless network.. I'm really frustrated with all this, I'll call them tomorrow and hope this is a recurring problem and they already have a solution.

Comment: When I turn on the VPN and try to access any website, it says that "www.any-website.com server DNS address could not be found" and seconds later "No internet". I forgot to mention that on my question

Comment: @PedroRocha is the DNS problem just with wifi or both ethernet.... Does you wifi work properly without the VPN?-I asked this one a couple of times?? Is the problem that you cannot get on the VPN or that you cannot get on the internet on the VPN? because those are two totally different problems... are you able get on the wifi-VPN and still get to your job's resources? can you still ping IP's at your job? Does the tunnel stay connected? I was under the impression that it was disconnecting. AND...when said your phone was unable to connect, did you mean VPN or just regular internet access?

Comment: Problems start when I turn on the VPN. Wifi works great without VPN. I can connect to the VPN for about 2 minutes, then it automatically disconnects. While connected, the DNS problem starts, still can't access my jobs resources or anything. I can connect to the VPN for a short amount of time, the problem is accessing the internet on the VPN. Sorry if it wasn't clear, I'm really confused here.

Comment: Are you saying that disconnection inevitable, even without you touching it? Or does it not happen until you try to use the internet? and this is ONLY on the wifi... I see the same DNS errors in both logs.... Are there any vpn related options on your router? also have you tried any lower MTU sizes on the wifi side?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115125/discussion-between-pedro-rocha-and-wu-tang).

Answer (score 0):

Extract from log:

```
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr pppd[7954]: local  IP address 10.10.1.2
Oct 13 08:05:21 pvqr pppd[7954]: remote IP address 10.10.1.1
```

Looks like `10.10.1.0/24` private addresses are being used for both the local and remote addresses. Can you configure the Huawei EG8145V5 to use something other than `10.10.1.0/24`?

With the ethernet connection, I think it is just a fluke there wasn't a IP address clash with the remote network.

Comment: might I asked where you derived those IPs?

Comment: Sorry copy/paste issue. I've fixed up my answer with correct IP subnet and included a snippet from the log file.

Comment: I didn't find a way to change the 10.10.1.2 IP on my router. Is this a configuration that I should do on my pc wifi settings or router? And what IP should I change it to?

Comment: Edited my question with router IP configs

Comment: I'm don't know if this is a correct assumption... the 10.10.1.0 network looks like the network that is assigned to your tunnel. I could be wrong (I've only done IPSEC site to site and SSL remote client VPNs)... but that 10.XXX IP may be configured on the VPN (by you) on your side OR it could be assigned to your PC by the server at your job. I definitely dont believe it is on your router (as your config clearly shows.)

Comment: Indeed, I conflated things.

I'm at a bit of a loss as to why you are getting the `Received out of order control packet` errors with WiFi